# How to infer the type of "(not .) . any" in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell by codewars.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/54589f3b52756d34d6000158/train/haskell

The answer is

```
module Codewars.Kata.AllNoneAny where

import Prelude hiding (all, any)

all, none, any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all  = (and .) . map
none = (not .) . any
any  = (or .) . map
```

1. `(.)` is `infixr 9`, so I think `(. any)` should be combine first. Then combine `(not .)`. Is this right?
2. How to combine `(not .) :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool` and `(. any) :: (([a] -> Bool) -> c) -> (a -> Bool) -> c` into `(not .) . any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`?

```hs
not :: Bool -> Bool
. :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool

(. any) :: (([a] -> Bool) -> c) -> (a -> Bool) -> c
(not .) :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
(not .) . any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

Comment: Fixity is irrelevant here, because parentheses are always considered first.

Comment: So what does `fixity` mean?  In `(not .) . any`, why `(not .) .` to combine `any`? Rather than `. any` to combine `(not .)`?

Comment: @zichaoliu Neither of those is what is really meant. In fact, `(not .) . any` uses `(.)` to combine `(not .)` and `any`.

Comment: Yes, @Daniel Wagner. `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. Should I replace `(b -> c)` by `(not .)` first. Or replace `(a -> b)` by `any` first? When I first replace `(.)`'s first param as my answer did, I can figure out `(not .) . any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`. But When I replace `(.)`'s second param first as my question, I can infer out `(not .) . any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`

Comment: @zichaoliu You should be able to do them in either order and get the same answer. (But it is better to think: both replacements happen at the same time.) Perhaps part of what is confusing you is that you have two different type variables named `a`? If you rename things in your type signatures so that they have disjoint variable names, perhaps it will be easier to see what is going on.

Comment: (I have added a short section to my answer expanding on my previous comment.)

Comment: Oh, Yes! Two different types with same name `a` made me confused. And lining up types tips is really help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to line up the types:

```
       (.)    :: (b             -> c          ) -> (a           -> b          ) -> a           -> c
(not .)       ::  ([d] -> Bool) -> [d] -> Bool
          any ::                                    (d -> Bool) -> [d] -> Bool
(not .) . any ::                                                                   (d -> Bool) -> [d] -> Bool
```

Or, starting with your final codeblock:

```
(. any) :: (([a] -> Bool) -> c) -> (a -> Bool) -> c
(not .) :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
(not .) . any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

Let's rename the `a`s so they are distinct, and insert some interpretive whitespace.

```
       (. any) :: (([a] -> Bool) -> c        ) -> (a -> Bool) -> c
(not .)        ::  (b   -> Bool) -> b -> Bool
(not .) . any  ::                                 (d -> Bool) -> [d] -> Bool
```

Now we can take `c ~ b -> Bool`, `b ~ [a]`, and `d ~ a` to unify these types. (Read `~` as equality. The `=` sign is not used for this to avoid syntax clashes.) Making these substitutions, we have:

```
       (. any) :: (([a] -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
(not .)        ::  ([a] -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
(not .) . any  ::                                   (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is left or right associative, does not matter, since there are parenthesis, the precedence is clear.

If we thus look at for example:

```
all  = (and .) . map
```

it is clear that the "outer" `.` is applied with `(and .)` as first operand and `map` as second operand.

The `(and .)` is a [*section of an infix operator* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator), so it is equivalent to `(.) and`.

It thus helps to first write the item in *canonical form*, with:

```
all = (.1) ((.2) and) map
```

I here added `(.1)` and `(.2)` to make the distinction clear.

First we will give the functions types. We use different type variables, so here the types are:

```
(.1) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
(.2) :: (e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
map :: (g -> h) -> ([g] -> [h])
```

Now we can start determining the type. We can first determine the type of `((.2) and)`, this thus uses `(.2) all` with `all` as parameter.

This thus means that we can determine the type as:

```
(.2)    :: (e      -> f   ) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
    and ::  [Bool] -> Bool
```

This thus means that the `f` type is the same as `Bool` and `e` has type `[Bool]`. Thus thus means that `(.2)` specializes to:

```
(.2) :: ([Bool] -> Bool) -> ((d -> [Bool]) -> (d -> Bool))
```

and the type of `((.2) and)` is thus `(d -> [Bool]) -> (d -> Bool)`.

Now we can determine the type of the entire expression, this thus `(.1)` with as parameters `((.2) and)` and `map`.

We thus can analyze this with:

```
(.1)               :: (b            -> c           ) -> ((a        -> b            ) -> (a -> c))
     (.2) and      ::  (d -> [Bool]) -> (d -> Bool)
               map ::                                     (g -> h) -> ([g] -> [h])
```

This thus means that `b` is the same type as `d -> [Bool]`, `c` equal to `d -> Bool`, `a` to `g -> h`, and `b` to `[g] -> [h]`.

Since we know that `b` is both equal to `d -> [Bool]` and `[g] -> [h]`, we thus know that `h ~ Bool` (`h` is the same type as `Bool`), and `d ~ [g]`.

It thus also means that `c ~ [g] -> Bool` and `a ~ g -> Bool`.

This thus means that the result of `(.1) ((.2) and) map` is `a -> c` and thus `(g -> Bool) -> ([g] -> Bool)` or thus:

```
(.1) ((.2) and) map :: (g -> Bool) -> [g] -> Bool
```

I leave determining the type of `(not .) . any` with the same procedure as exercise.

Comment: `all = (.1) ((.2) all) map` you mean `all = (.1) ((.2) and) map` right? That error is repeated in a couple of places.

Comment: @cafce25: aarrggghhh... yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of answering your question about how the solution you supplied works, I'd like to point out that the solution, while pretty, is not one most people would write, and many could not easily read it. Instead, you might write out the definitions longhand first, and then look for patterns that you can abstract or factor out.

```
all, none, any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all f xs = and (map f xs)
any f xs = or (map f xs)
none f xs = not (any f xs)
```

The most obvious thing then is to note this pattern of "Given two functions and a list, run one function over the list and give the result to the other function".

```
comp2 :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
comp2 outer inner = \f xs -> outer (inner f xs)

all, none, any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all = comp2 and map
any = comp2 or map
none = comp2 not any
```

I've put the somewhat tacky lambda in `comp2`'s implementation to illustrate how closely it matches the original, longhand definitions of `all` and friends.

At this point if you're really excited about point-free definitions you might realize that `comp2` can be defined point-free as `comp2 = (.) . (.)`, and you can get to the "pretty" definitions from there. But there's no real need to take that step, or really any of the previous steps after the longhand definitions in my first code block: they are quite clear already.

Comment: Absolutely! Code easy to read is most importent. "According to desire to construct function", tips is really help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
(not .) . :: (a1 -> a2 -> Bool) -> (a1 -> a2 -> Bool)
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
(not .) . any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```